# Is it possible to save an element that was clicked on JavaScript for later use in functions?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently programming a checkers interface with JS, HTML and CSS. I have already built both the board and the pieces. I want to write functions in order to move the pieces now. I want to do so by asking the user to click on the piece, and then asking him/her to click on the square they want to move it to. Assuming it's a legal move, is there a way for me to save the clicked piece as a variable or anything else and to use it later in functions (which will move it to the requested square)?
Here is my (very long) JS code (combines some CSS and HTML):

```
var player = 1;
function CreateBoard() {
    var board = document.createElement("table");
    board.cellSpacing = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var tr1 = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            var td1 = document.createElement("td");
            td1.setAttribute("id", "td" + i + j);
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                    td1.style.backgroundColor = "beige";
                else
                    td1.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            }
            else {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                    td1.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                else
                    td1.style.backgroundColor = "beige";
            }
            tr1.appendChild(td1);
        }
        board.appendChild(tr1);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(board);
}

function DeployPieces() {
    CreateBoard();
    var pieceIndex = 1;
    var isEmpty = new Array(8);
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        isEmpty[i] = new Array(8);
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            isEmpty[i][j] = true;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (i < 3) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                for (var j = 1; j < 8; j += 2) {
                    var td1 = document.getElementById("td" + i + j);
                    var circle1 = document.createElement("span");
                    circle1.setAttribute("class", "redCircle");
                    circle1.setAttribute("id", "circle" + i + j);
                    circle1.setAttribute("onclick", "AlertToPressOnSquare(player);");
                    td1.appendChild(circle1);
                    isEmpty[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
            else { 
                for (var j = 0; j < 8; j += 2) {
                    var td2 = document.getElementById("td" + i + j);
                    var circle2 = document.createElement("span");
                    circle2.setAttribute("class", "redCircle");
                    circle2.setAttribute("id", "circle" + i + j);
                    circle2.setAttribute("onclick", "AlertToPressOnSquare(player);");
                    td2.appendChild(circle2);
                    isEmpty[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (i > 4) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                for (var j = 1; j < 8; j += 2) {
                    var td3 = document.getElementById("td" + i + j);
                    var circle3 = document.createElement("span");
                    circle3.setAttribute("class", "whiteCircle");
                    circle3.setAttribute("id", "circle" + i + j);
                    circle3.setAttribute("onclick", "AlertToPressOnSquare(player);");
                    td3.appendChild(circle3);
                    isEmpty[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (var j = 0; j < 8; j += 2) {
                    var td4 = document.getElementById("td" + i + j);
                    var circle4 = document.createElement("span");
                    circle4.setAttribute("class", "whiteCircle");
                    circle4.setAttribute("id", "circle" + i + j);
                    circle4.setAttribute("onclick", "AlertToPressOnSquare(player);");
                    td4.appendChild(circle4);
                    isEmpty[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
function AlertToPressOnPiece(player) {
    alert("Player " + player + ", please press on the piece you would like to move");
    if (player == 1)
        player = 2;
    else if (player == 2)
        player = 1;
}
function AlertToPressOnSquare(player) {
    alert("Player " + player + ", please press on the square to which you would like to move the piece");
    if (player == 1)
        player = 2;
    else if (player == 2)
        player = 1;

}
```

Now, I have id's for all the td's and circles (I did it so that the id is the element's initial location (for instance 01 = i = 0, j = 1)). I also know how I'll move the piece later when I have it saved. I just need a simple way to access the clicked circle later on (maybe through its id or anything ).
Thank you

Comment: There's probably no reason for those setting ids on those Elements at all. If you want to know which element was clicked `circle1.setAttribute("onclick", "AlertToPressOnSquare(player);");` should be like `circle1.onclick = function(){ AlertToPressOnSqaure(player);  /* keyword this or circle1 is your clicked Element */ }`

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to save this `circle1` for later use? What should I do in this case?

Comment: Assign it to a higher scoped variable. If you don't know how many you want to save, use an Array.

Comment: How can I do that assignment you mentioned?

Comment: The same way you assign `player`.

Comment: Oh so just to use it as a global variable?

Comment: I prefer to scope most variables to a lower level *(I like instance based code myself)* than global, but that will work.

Comment: So I'll try to save `circle1` the same way I did with `player`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another thing just came to my mind. How does it fit with the fact that I dynamically create the circles in the `DeployPieces()` function?

Comment: Lets say you have `let lastClicked;` at the top of the page... then you can do like  `function clickedIt(){ AlertToPressOnSqaure(player);  lastClicked = this; }` then do like `circle1.onclick = clickedIt;`. The beauty of `this`, is you don't have to rewrite a separate function to assign to your other nodes. Now you can reuse, the same function because `this`, within the method of an Object *(in this case the Element)* refers to the Object.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the whole element to a variable, but it's probably best to just save the x and y position of the piece. You can create public variables `selectedX` and `selectedY` or create a single variable, such as `selected = { x: 5, y: 6 }`. Then, at any time, you can get the element by doing:

```
var element = document.getElementById('td' + selected.x + selected.y);
```

This is based off the format of how you assigned ids above:

```
td1.setAttribute("id", "td" + i + j);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I couldn't understand you that much. I want to save the circle that was clicked. So should I use this `selected`` variable for each piece? How can I save the clicked button as a variable for later use?

Comment: When you're calling `AlertToPressOnPiece` with the onclick, you probably want to pass along the i and j: `.setAttribute("onclick", "AlertToPressOnSquare(" + i + "," + j + ");");` There's no need to pass along `player` since that's already public and accessible from anywhere. So, within `function AlertToPressOnSquare(i, j) {}`, `i` and `j` will be the circle they clicked on. You can save `i` and `j` in some public variable. At any time you can then do `document.getElementById('circle' + i + j)`

Comment: Thank you so much! This sounds awesome. But why is the `AlertToPressOnSquare` parameters different in the 2 examples you gave? One is `AlertToPressOnSquare(" + i + "," + j + ")` and the other is AlertToPressOnSquare(i, j)

Comment: Besides, are you sure there is no issue with the quotation marks in `"AlertToPressOnSquare(" + i + "," + j + ");")`? I didn't quite get the structure there

Comment: It's trying to generate a string in the format, say, `AlertToPressOnSquare(4,5);` You can try console.log or alerting it to see if it's correct.

Comment: That seems to work. But how can I save i and j in public variables given that they are always changing within the for loops?

Comment: Ah, so I just mean you use that to setup all those `AlertToPressOnSquare` calls. Within `AlertToPressOnSquare(x, y) {}` is where `x` and `y` will be set and contain the values you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

It took me all day to come up with an incomplete example to show you how you might want to start your gameboard. There is still a lot to do. It's late and I've given all I'm willing at this point. Good Luck!

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, GamePlayer, GameBoard, GamePiece; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = /Mobi/i.test(nav.userAgent);
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = (node, className)=>{
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.add(...classNames);
  return aC;
}
rC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.remove(...classNames);
  return rC;
}
tC = (node, className)=>{
  node.classList.toggle(className);
  return tC;
}
GamePlayer = function(player){
  this.player = player; this.pieces = []; this.using; 
  this.addPiece = (piece, x, y)=>{
    this.pieces.push([piece, x, y]);
    return this;
  }
}
GameBoard = function(wide = 8, high = 8){
  this.table = M('table'); this.tbody = M('tbody');
  this.table.className = 'gameboard'; this.using;
  const t = this, all = [];
  const sizeIt = where=>{
    this.table.style.width = where.getBoundingClientRect().height+'px';
     let q = Q('td', this.tbody), tb = this.table.getBoundingClientRect(), tt = tb.top, tl = tb.left, b, bt, bl;
    for(let n of q){
      b = n.getBoundingClientRect(); bt = b.top-tt; bl = b.left-tl;
      all.push([bt, bt+b.height, bl, bl+b.width, n]);
    }
  }
  for(let i=0,tr,shit=0; i<high; i++){
    tr = M('tr');
    for(let n=0,td; n<wide; n++){
      td = M('td'); tr.appendChild(td); 
    }
    this.tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  const grabIt = function(){
    if(!t.using){
      this.style.width = this.style.height = this.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width+'px';
      aC(this, 'using'); aC(t.table, 'using'); t.using = this;
    }
  }
  const moveIt = e=>{
    const u = this.using;
    if(u){
      const s = u.style, h = u.getBoundingClientRect().width/2;
      s.top = e.clientY-h+'px'; s.left = e.clientX-h+'px';
    }
  }
  const dropIt = e=>{
    if(this.using){
      const tb = this.table, x = e.clientX-tb.offsetLeft, y = e.clientY-tb.offsetTop;
      let n;
      for(let a of all){
        n = a[4];
        if(y >= a[0] && y <= a[1] && x >= a[2] && x <= a[3] && !n.hasChildNodes()){
          n.appendChild(this.using);
          break;
        }
      }
      rC(this.table, 'using'); rC(this.using, 'using'); this.using = undefined;
    }
  }
  this.addPiece = (player, x, y, piece)=>{
    if(mobile){
      piece.piece.ontouchstart = grabIt;
    }
    else{
      piece.piece.onmousedown = grabIt;
    }
    player.addPiece(piece, x, y);
    this.tbody.rows[y].cells[x].appendChild(piece.piece);
    return this;
  }
  this.appendTo = where=>{
    where.appendChild(this.table); sizeIt(where); 
    onresize = ()=>{
      sizeIt(where);
    }
    if(mobile){
      ontouchmove = e=>{
        moveIt(e.touches[0]);
      }
      ontouchend = e=>{
        dropIt(e.touches[0]);
      }
    }
    else{
      onmousemove = moveIt; onmouseup = dropIt;
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.table.appendChild(this.tbody);
}
GamePiece = function(className){
  this.piece = M('div'); this.piece.className = className;
}
// tiny Library above - magic below can be put on a separate page using a load Event *(except // end load line)*
const board = new GameBoard, player1 = new GamePlayer('player 1'), player2 = new GamePlayer('player 2');
const page = I('page');
function redDisk(){
  return new GamePiece('red_disk');
}
function blackDisk(){
  return new GamePiece('black_disk');
}
for(let i=0,n=1,p,l=8; i<l; i+=2,n+=2){
  p = redDisk(); board.addPiece(player1, i, 5, p); 
  p = redDisk(); board.addPiece(player1, n, 6, p); 
  p = redDisk(); board.addPiece(player1, i, 7, p);
  p = blackDisk(); board.addPiece(player2, n, 0, p); 
  p = blackDisk(); board.addPiece(player2, i, 1, p);
  p = blackDisk(); board.addPiece(player2, n, 2, p);
}
board.appendTo(page);
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{ /* set font separate to avoid white space issues */
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0; font-size:0; border:0; outline:none; overflow:hidden; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
  -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none; user-select:none;
}
html,body,.full,.gameboard>tbody{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
#page{
  display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; background:#333;
}
.gameboard{
  table-layout:fixed; height:100%; background:#000; border-collapse:collapse; 
}
.gameboard tr,.gameboard td{
  width:100%; height:calc(100% / 8);
}
.gameboard tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(odd),.gameboard tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(even){
  background:beige;
}
.gameboard td>div{
  cursor:pointer; width:100%; height:100%; border:double #555 4px; border-radius:50%;
}
.red_disk{
  background:lightgrey; /* background:url('red_disk.png'); */
}
.black_disk{
  background:tan; /* background:url('black_disk.png'); */
}
.gameboard.using,.gameboard.using *{
  cursor:grab;
}
td>.using{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='full' id='page'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS:
I would personally go with a canvas design, instead... but this is an example of what you might want to, kind of, do.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your great effort to help me with that.